# How to add Rotate animation to translate animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I need  define the Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF in xml and not in the code ? I am trying to add a rotate animation to go along with my translate animation(which is defined in the xml) However the below code is not working and I can find the parameter pivotXType in the xml. Please help...

```
anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 10,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                                    0);
                anim.setInterpolator(interpolator);
                anim.setDuration(mDuration);
                anim.setFillEnabled(true);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
                ((AnimationSet)view_1_anim_c).addAnimation(anim);
                apa1.startAnimation(view_1_anim_c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`AnimationSet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html) or in animation XML the [`<set>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#set-element) tag.